# When hooking fopen with LD_PRELOAD on a 32 bit version of a game, fopen calls only seem to happen when the game first starts. Why is that?

Tags: c++, linux, hook, ld

I have this code I'm using with LD_PRELOAD on linux to hook fopen calls, and I'm trying to use it on a game. It works fine on the 64 bit version of the game, but on the 32 bit version, it seems like fopen just gets called 65 times when the game first starts, then never gets called again. I also hooked freopen and fdopen just to check if those were being called, and they weren't. Does anyone know why this is happening, and what function the 32 bit version might be using instead?

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <dlfcn.h>
static auto originalFopen = reinterpret_cast<FILE * (*)(const char* path, const char* mode)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen"));
static auto originalFdopen = reinterpret_cast<FILE * (*)(int fd, const char* mode)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fdopen"));
static auto originalFreopen = reinterpret_cast<FILE * (*)(const char* path, const char* mode, FILE* stream)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "freopen"));

FILE* f = originalFopen("TEST.txt", "w");

FILE* fopen(const char* path, const char* mode)
{
    std::fwrite("idk1\n", 1, 5, f);

    return originalFopen(path, mode);
}

FILE* fdopen(int fd, const char* mode)
{
    std::fwrite("idk2\n", 1, 5, f);

    return originalFdopen(fd, mode);
}

FILE* freopen(const char* path, const char* mode, FILE* stream)
{
    std::fwrite(path, 1, std::strlen(path), f);
    std::fwrite("\n", 1, 1, f);

    return originalFreopen(path, mode, stream);
}
```

This is the source code of the game I'm hooking: https://github.com/FrictionalGames/AmnesiaTheDarkDescent

Comment: open, openat? What does strace show? Does it even open files?

Comment: Yes it calls openat a lot.

Comment: So likely just not using FILE streams but raw file descriptors.

Comment: Why does the 64 bit version just use fopen?

Comment: Someone figured this out. It was calling fopen64 instead.